# Yii show all pages in pagination

Tags: yii, pagination

I'm using yii framework. For example, in one table I have 400 rows. In admin view, where CGridView is I have 20 rows per page (20 pages). In my pagination I have number from 1st to 10th page. When I go on 15th page, I have 10-20, But I want to show all pages under my CGridView (from first to last).

I don't think that I should copy some code, because I think this is some option, but I didn't find it in yii documentation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `maxButtonCount`  in `pager`  and assign a high value (the Yii1 doc don't show a proper value for no limits the using an high value you obtain the same result)

eg :

```
     'pager'=>array(             
        'header'=>'',
        'cssFile'=>false,
        'maxButtonCount'=>24,
        'selectedPageCssClass'=>'active',
        'hiddenPageCssClass'=>'disabled',
        'firstPageCssClass'=>'previous',
        'lastPageCssClass'=>'next',
        'firstPageLabel'=>'<<',
        'lastPageLabel'=>'>>',
        'prevPageLabel'=>'<',
        'nextPageLabel'=>'>',
        'maxButtonCount'=>20000;
```